# Analyze the convergence of the following integral $\int_0^1 \frac{e^{f(x)+\sqrt{x}}}{x+\sqrt{x}} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Analyze the following statement and prove if it's true or not:

If $$f(x) \; \text{continuous in} \; [0,1] \; \rightarrow \; \int_0^1 \frac{e^{f(x)+\sqrt{x}}}{x+\sqrt{x}} \, dx$$ is an improper integral and it diverges.

The only thing that i know is that it is an improper integral because $g(x)= \frac{e^{f(x)+\sqrt{x}}}{x+\sqrt{x}}$ it is undefined at $x=0$. Also, by knowing that $f(x) \; \text{continuous in} \; [0,1]$ i know that $\exists \; f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \; f(x)$

I'm tempted to use the comparison test by I wouldn't know to which. Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if $f$ is continuous, $f$ is bounded, in particular $e^{f(x)+\sqrt{x}}$ is bounded and nonzero as $x\to 0^+$. why must the integral diverge then?

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)$ is continuous, so that $h(x)=e^{f(x)+\sqrt{x}}$ is continuous. We use mean value theorem in integral calculus.
$c\in [0,1] $;
$L=\int_{0}^{1} h(x)\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x}}dx=h(c)\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x}}dx=h(c)2\ln{2}$

$L$ converges.

Comment: Can you apply the mean value theorem for integrals like that ? I mean, isn't it $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)=f(c)(b-a) \; c \in [a,b]$? It would seem like you only use $h(x)$ and not the entire integrand.

Answer (score 0):

Being undefined at $x=0$ is neither here nor there; what matters is that it has a vertical asymptote there. Continuity of $f$ at $0$ means $f$ itself approaches a finite value at $0;$ consequently $e^{f(x) + \sqrt x}$ approaches a value that is not $0.$ Therefore, the function being integrated approaches $\infty$ at $0.$

Comment: Yes, it approaches $\infty$ at $0$. Nevertheless, it is integrable, just as $1/\sqrt x$ is integrable (in the sense that it is an improper integral that converges).

Comment: @TonyK ; Whether it is integrable or not is not a question I was addressing here (so this is at most a partial answer). Did you take my answer to be attempting to say something about that?

Comment: Well that's what the OP's question is. So yes, I did. Otherwise I don't know why you bothered to post.